# Can't Access Private Git Repo With Personal Access Token

Tags: git, github

I've never used a private Git repo until recently. I'm having trouble with gaining access to my private repo from my local machine. Last month, GitHub updated the way you access private repositories. Now you can't use your username and password. I'm given this message when I try with the personal access token: `remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/[Org]/[Repo].git/' not found`.

I've already initialized my local repository. Now I just need to connect it to my private remote repository. I'd like to use my personal access token instead of ssh.

Here are the commands I'm using on Windows:

```
git remote add origin https://[UserName]:[Token]@github.com/[Org]/[Repo].git
git add .
git commit -m "Commit" ---> Output: On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean
git push --set-upstream origin master ---> Output: Gives me the error
```

Comment: Does `https://github.com/[Org]/[Repo].git/` in fact exist? If so, can you clone it?

Comment: Well [Org] and [Repo] are placeholders. I can clone it actually. Here is what I get as a message: `Cloning into '[Repo]'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.`

Comment: If your token has a typo or other error in it (or isn't set at all on GitHub) you will see this behavior for any repository that *anyone* can read: it will be there for you to clone, but you won't be able to `git push` to it because you're not authenticated as you, and the error they give for this is "not found" instead of "permission denied" because "permission denied" is too informative (seriously: for security purposes one doesn't want to distinguish between "exists but no access" and "does not exist": this is pointless for a public readable repo, but GitHub don't check that first).

Comment: So it seems admin does not give enough permissions to push code. I changed my role to an owner and it works now. It would be nice if roles were explained better on GitHub. Thanks for the help. It wouldn't make sense to say "Does not exist" instead of "Exists but no access" when attempting to push when not authenticated because then someone would just need to execute a clone command instead to see that it in fact exists. If that's truly a security measure, it's a poor one and only creates confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main takeaway from my issue is to make sure the role you're assigned is allowed to push to the private repository. My team and I assumed that an admin would be able to push, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Also, you can use either of these for your origin:

`https://[Token]@github.com/[Org]/[Repo].git`

or

`https://[UserName]:[Token]@github.com/[Org]/[Repo].git`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your statement "Last month, GitHub updated the way you access private repositories. Now, instead of using your password, you use a personal access token. " is true at all. You can do that, right.

To use the token add your repo url like so:

```
git remote add origin https://[Token]@github.com/[Org]/[Repo].git
```

Comment: So no need for the username then?

Comment: I guess you're right. It looks like personal access tokens have been a thing for a while now on GitHub. It's just that last month they removed the ability to use your username and password.

Comment: It looks like you can use your username too with your access token as I was attempting to do. You don't need it though. Only the access token is necessary as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different answer worked for me. I found that I was suddenly unable to push to one of my repos, but could still push to all the others with no issue. I thought it was something wrong with my token or my personal permissions, but I confirmed that I had admin + write permissions, and that the token I was using had permissions on the repo in question and was unexpired. I even thought something might have gotten corrupted locally, or that updating git might have broken something, but I couldn't find anything wrong. Finally, I checked my remote URL on the problem repo, and it was `https://github.com/<my_user>/<my_problem_repo>.git`. I then checked the remote URL on one of the repos I was still able to push to, and it was `git@github.com:<my_user>/my_repo_that_I_can_push_to>.git`. I changed the remote URL in the problem repo to be in `git@github` format using `git remote set-url origin <url>` and was finally able to push to it again.

I believe the reason why I was "suddenly" unable to push to that one repo is that I had originally been using password authentication, so that https URL it was using was no problem, but since I last pushed to that repo a long time ago, git deprecated password authentication (?), and I switched to using a PAT in my system's `GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN` env var for authentication. But you can't use PATs with HTTPS URLs (you need to use a git@github URL or *maybe?* an SSH url). I must have updated the remote URLs on my other repositories but forgot to update this one, explaining why I could push to every repo except one.

If anyone comes to this question because they're mysteriously not able to push to one or only a few of their repositories, check if your remote url is one of the formats that supports PATs (NOT HTTPS) with `git remote get-url remote`.